# Storing Large Quantities of Time Series

Tags: postgresql, database-design, timestamp, time-series-database

What is the recommended (type) of database design for storing large amounts of time-series data?

The dataset:

- 2 million time-series;
- Each of the time-series contains around 500 timestamps;
- At each of the time-stamp there are multiple variables (meta-data);
- It would be optimal if meta-data could later easily be ingested into the database (preferably with a Python API) .

I have looked into PostgreSQL, but so far I have been struggling to set it up for many time-series.

Comment: describe the meta-data that goes with each timestamp  how complex is this data?

Comment: you probably want a database that is optimized for time-series analysis. Any database can do it, but some query patterns are specific to time-series that some databases aren't optimized for. timescale.com is based on postgresql but is focused on time-series analysis

Comment: The meta-data will features to enrich the dataset. They might be scraped or coming from other datasets. It is for a natural sciences project, so things like humidity etc. I don't expect them to have complex nested structures.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Timescale. I remember having a look at that earlier. Probably I will have to set up the structure as a hypertable. E.g, https://blog.timescale.com/tutorials/how-to-explore-timescaledb-using-simulated-iot-sensor-data/

Answer (score 0):

If you use a time-series database, the volume of data you are describing wouldn't be considered large. Take for example [QuestDB](https://questdb.io), an Apache 2.0 licensed time-series database. It can easily do what you ask just by simply creating a table and defining which column is your `designated timestamp`. The time series dimensions would be configured as `symbol` (a specialised string type) or as `string`, and the dimensions would be configured as a numeric type. There are also `uuid` and `geohash` native types.

Table creation can be done using Postgresql-compatible SQL (and libraries) or just start ingesting using the official clients, including the [**Python**](https://github.com/questdb/py-questdb-client) one, and table will be automatically created.

Querying the data is done via SQL, with python you can use **psycopg** for your queries as if this were a postgreSQL. QuestDB offers some specific extensions to sample data, aggregate by time intervals, join by approximate time, or working with time-ranges, but other than that it looks like standard SQL.

Ingestion performance is fast (you can ingest over 1MM rows per second) and querying speed is very fast.

Regarding size, [at the demo site](https://demo.questdb.io) there is a table containing 1.6 billion rows. If you execute some of the sample queries you will see aggregates return in just below half a second, when scanning the full table. If you limit to "only" one year of data (several hundred million rows) it should return in **below 20 milliseconds**. No indexes required.